# How to properly define subclass constructors in Javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, class, this, subclass

I have trouble making a constructor for subclasses in JS. The constructors for classes work fine though!

```
//defining base class State
class State {
    constructor(){
        this.someText = "someText";
    }
    start(){

     }

     update(){

    }

    exit(){

    }
}

//defining subclass preloadState

class preloadState extends State{
    constructor(){
        this.ball = "red";
    }

    start(){
        console.log(this.ball);
    }
}

var state = new preloadState;
state.start();

}
```

When running the code, I get the error `this.ball` is not defined in the preloadState class. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can use `this` in a subclass' constructor, you have to call `super`:

```
class preloadState extends State {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.ball = "red";
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n0ek40ph/

Another option is not to override the constructor:

```
class preloadState extends State {
    start() {
        this.ball = "red";
        console.log(this.ball);
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n0ek40ph/3/

More in depth:

- http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Great! Just what I wanted. Follow up questions: 1. Is this.ball accessible across all functions in preloadState? 2. How would I pass an instance of preloadState in a function?

Comment: Good! 1: yes, in all methods you call after `preloadState.start()`. 2: I don't understand this question.

Comment: 2. Say I have an object of preloadState: `var state = new preloadState()`. Now say I want to use `state.start()` in some other function. `function foo(state){ state.start()}`. Would that be possible? Can I pass a class object in another function?